# Can I add REST to my existing BlazeDS spring webservice?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, blazeds

I have existing blazeDS web-services which need to be preserved as is for various legacy reasons.
I now have the need to expose the same functional services via a rest api and marshall the previous binary VOs via json.
I want to know if I can somehow use both @RemotingDestination and @RequestMapping at the same time on the same class? Have it cater to both request types?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to expose the same functionality to both REST and Blaze is to create a wrapper methods for the REST endpoint and have it proxy through to the original Blaze exposed method.

Simple Example assuming a simple GET:

```
@Service("userService")
@RemotingDestination(channels={"my-amf","my-secure-amf"})
public class UserService {

    @RemotingExclude
    @RequestMapping("/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserByIdRest(@PathVariable String id) {
        return this.getUserById(id);
    }

    @RemotingInclude
    public String getUserById(String id) {
       //..
       return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather use the same method if possible so I'll wait a bit to see if someone offers a different way but I would like to ask you if the @RemotingInclude is optional? I'm asking because my current blaze-ds services (which I did not write) don't have it but they of course work. Maybe this is required only when using @RemotingExclude? Thanks

Comment: NP, I always thought that @ RemotingInclude was required, but guess not since your current implementation is working without it. I would be curious to know if it continued to work after you add the @ RemotingExclude.  Personally, I prefer to explicitly annotate my service methods for clarity.  Good luck.